# Algebra problem with divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b$ be natural numbers so that $a \ge 2, b \ge 2$ and $a^{2}b^{2}$ is divisible by $a^{2}-ab+b^{2}$ Prove that $a$, $b$ are not relatively prime numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: At least one can try to prove by contradiction so that *some work* could have been done I suppose?

Comment: Step 0: show that $a^2 - ab + b^2 > 1$. Step 1: hence there is a prime $p$ dividing $a^2 - ab + b^2$. Step 2: hence $p$ divides $a^2b^2$ …

Answer (score 0):

${\bf Hint}\quad \begin{align} 
&(\color{#c00}a,\!\overbrace{a^2\!-\!ab\!+\!b^2}^{\Large\ \equiv\ \color{#0a0}{ b^2}\bmod{\color{#c00} a}}\!\!)=(a,\color{#0a0}{b^2})\\
&(b,\ a^2\!-\!ab\!+\!b^2)=(b,a^2)
\end{align}\ $  $ \begin{align}\\  \\ {\rm so}\ \ \ (a^2b^2,\,a^2\!-\!ab\!+\!b^2)=1 \iff (a,b)=1\\ \\ \end{align}$